# My code to change the current directory in C++ keeps giving me the Segmentation Fault: 11 error

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "unistd.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){

char *directory = NULL;

cout << "Enter the directory you want to enter: ";

//taking input
cin >> directory;

//changing the directory
chdir(directory);

return 0;
}
```

My compiler says that the error occurs at line 7 (`char *directory = NULL;`)

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's got nothing to do with `chdir()`, rather the problem is that you are telling `cin` to write data via a NULL pointer.

The proper solution is to use a `std::string` to hold the path-string instead:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
   std::string directory;

   std::cout << "Enter the directory you want to enter: " << std::endl;

   //taking input
   std::cin >> directory;

   //changing the directory
   chdir(directory.c_str());

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use <> for file in compiler library

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>  // 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string directory;

   cout << "Enter the directory you want to enter: " << endl;

   //taking input
   cin >> directory;

   //changing the directory
   chdir(&directory[0]);

   return 0;
}
```